# @font-face displaying in all browsers but not android and IOS. Tried fontsquirrell and change mime types

Tags: android, ios, font-face

I am having trouble getting the @font-face to work.   It is displaying fine in all browsers apart from IOS and android.

I have gone through the http://www.fontsquirrel.com to get the following code:

```
@font-face {   font-family: 'philly_sansregular';
src: url('phillysansps-webfont.eot');
src: url('phillysansps-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('phillysansps-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('phillysansps-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('phillysansps-webfont.svg#philly_sansregular') format('svg');
}
```

I have also added the following to my .htaccess file in the root:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```

Can anyone help?

The website in question is [enter link description here](http://www.howtostreetdance.com)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:  I had not specified the correct url.  For some reason it was pointing to a different location so I had to use the full URL.  Also I found out that the reason it wont work properly on android and iphone is because there are only a certain number of web safe/mobile safe fonts.